# Problem with getting only numbers from row and sum all rows

Tags: sql

I have a query that getting numbers from rows.  Example row: 1TP 2 TP. Query getting data 1,2 from this row.  But it is not possible to sum numbers from this row.  I would like to sum 1+2, but ',' cause that it is impossible to sum rows. When I delete ',' then I have problem because visible data is 12 instead 2 separate numbers: 1 and 2.How to devide it because with row 12TP it is not a problem but when row looks like 3TP 2 TP then result from query is 1 number: 32 instead of 3 and 2.  And sum of rows is wrong.
Thank you very much for your support

Query:

```
select 
    root_cause,
    regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(root_cause_details,'[^[:digit:]]+',','),
      '^,|,$','' Numbers
    )
FROM booker.o_remedy
WHERE
item = 'EU - Writing Requests'
AND extract(week from (date(resolved_date))) = 28
AND extract(year from (date(create_date))) = 2021
AND root_cause_details ILike '%TP%'
```

Example of table:
column numbers:  extracted numbers by query
[image: TABLE VIEW]

Comment: You should add your table and sample data. Tag your database too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you are using, but I think you just need to specify that the matching should be global rather than just the first one.  Also, you can use `trim()` to remove the first elements.

You don't specify the database you are using, but in Postgres, this looks like:

```
trim(',' from regexp_replace(root_cause_details,'[^0-9]+', ',', 'g'))
```

The syntax would be similar in any other database that supports `regexp_replace()`.